# onClick on a TableRow in React MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add an `onClick` listener to my TableRow. 
To my surprise, simply giving an onClick prop like this works:

```
<TableRow onClick = {()=> console.log("clicked")}>
    <TableCell> Content </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

I couldn't understand this behavior because, looking at the code : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow I don't see a definition for the `onClick` prop anywhere.

So, why is it working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

onClick is not Material UI feature (or prop).

Instead it is a native React onClick function that you can read more on:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Whatever feature you find in React docs, you can use in MaterialUI and on any MaterialUI element, since MaterialUI is based on React.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `TableRow` that listens to `onClick`, but rather the underlying component, which is React's `tr` by default, because `TableRow` passes to it all the props it gets and doesn't use.

If you supply a different underlying component with `<TableRow component={...} onClick={...} />`, then that component will have to do something with `onClick` if you want to keep the functionality.

---

This is what happens:

1. `TableRow` takes the following props:

   - `classes`, `className`, `component`, `hover` and `selected` ([line 39](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L39))
   - `...other` ([line 45](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L45)), which contains all the other props that you pass to it
2. It then returns a `Component` ([line 50](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L50)) which is whatever you passed as the `component` prop (see [line 82](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L82) for the prop type), or, if you didn't pass anything, then `tr` by default ([line 42](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L42) and [line 33](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L33))
3. The `tr` component then takes all the props sent by `TableRow`, which are:

   - `ref` ([line 51](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L51))
   - `className` ([line 52](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L52))
   - `role` ([line 62](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L62))
   - using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), everything from `other` ([line 63](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableRow/TableRow.js#L63)) which will include your `onClick`

Comment: could you add an example on using the spread operator with other?